Finding the answers to the problems in the tutorials on the Tinkercad website
I'm trying to learn Tinkercad by going through the tutorials on the website. I'm having some trouble with them, and I can't figure out where or how to get help. I've searched for the answers on the Internet but have not found anything. Is there a way to get the answers to the tutorial problems on Tinkercad to see what I'm doing wrong?
I'm currently having trouble with two exercises. On the Moving Shapes tutorial, I am having trouble with the Tree exercise, and on the Rotating Shapes tutorial, I am having trouble with the pyramid pointing to target exercise. I am particularly frustrated with the Tree exercise, because I am certain I have my tree exactly as the model tree, but the website still says I am wrong.
When I get the answer wrong, an info box pops up, but it doesn't actually contain any info. Plus it disappears pretty fast, so even if there were info, I don't know that I would be able to read it quickly enough.
I want to find the correct answers to not just these two challenges but also to other challenges so if I have trouble with future ones I will have something to turn to.
I'm dumbfounded by the fact that Tinkercad doesn't provide answers or even hints to the problems on their tutorials. How are we supposed to learn if we can't see what we did wrong and what we should have done?

Your question risks being closed for vagueness. There's insufficiently specific information for someone to duplicate the difficulties you are experiencing and there are no images provided for any specific problem. Consider creating a sequence of text and interspersed images representing the failure(s) you are experiencing. An observer and prospective answer creator may be able to ferret out the problem and/or duplicate your example, to better provide a solution.
